# Desmos Factorial function

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

I was playing around with gamma function approximations and I was curious of which approximation Desmos uses. It extends negatives so it can’t be the Stirling formula. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: It may be using the reflection formula $z! = 1/[(-z)! \mathrm{sinc}(\pi z)]$ for negative values.

Comment: On wikipedia there is an example of how you can approximate the Gamma function on the interval $[1,2]$, and then drop down (or go up) to any other value using $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$. Alternatively there are various integral formulae, and the Weierstrass and Euler product formulae

Comment: Stirling's formula is a poor approximant anyway compared to longer expansions of the "Stirling series" or clever truncations: $$x!\approx x^xe^{-x}\sqrt{\pi}(8x^3+4x^2+x+1/30)^{1/6}$$Is due to Ramanujan and brings in the first $5$ or $6$ terms of the series

Comment: There is also a Taylor series about $1$ for the gamma function and also a Fourier series (called the (Malmsten-)Kummer series) on the interval $[0,1]$, and with all of these tricks you use $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$ to bootstrap values to the whole real line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I think I found what it uses. Thanks to @eyeballfrog for suggesting the reflection formula. I did a bit of research and found the [Lanczos Approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation) combined with the reflection formula to match the factorial function is Desmos almost perfectly. Here is the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pexapwpz7f). I’ve also made a C++ implementation of the algorithm if anyone else wants to use it [here](https://github.com/Bobingstern/Lanczos-Approximation)